# Using Django Choices in Template Logic

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a model, say:

```
from model_utils import Choices

class Day(models.Model):
    WEATHER = Choices(
        ('r', 'rainy', 'Rainy'),
        ('s', 'sunny', 'Sunny'),
    )
    weather = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=WEATHER)
```

Is there a way, in the presentation, to use the logical keywords e.g.:

```
{% ifequal monday.weather Day.WEATHER.rainy %}
It rained monday
{% endifequal %}
```

I am aware of the [get_FOO_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) method, but would rather not test against a hardcoded string (e.g., monday.get_weather_display == 'Rainy'). Is there a template tag or inclusion or some way to refer to this decleration in the model? Or at least a best practices suggestion for doing choices-related logic in the template? I have found little evidence in the docs, can't really wrap my head around the source, and all questions I've found on here are people looking for the get_FOO_display method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write a property method in the model

```
class Day(models.Model):

    [...]

    @property
    def is_rainy(self):
        return self.weather == self.WEATHER.rainy
```

And in my template I would check:

```
{% if monday.is_rainy %}
    It rained monday
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I (foolishly) had already implemented this in my code and had forgotten about it! One can use the instance to refer to the choice possibilities, per my example:

```
{% if monday.weather == monday.WEATHER.rainy %}
[...]
```

I would delete the question, but the fact remains it is not explained very clearly in the docs and does not appear to be a duplicate of anything I was able to find on stackoverflow.

Comment: I would still recommend you put the logic in your model instead of the template.

Comment: That is probably the wise thing to do, however is possibly untenable/messy if one has many choices to check with or against.. although I suppose at that point there might be bigger problems.